# Как сравнить два файла .csv и записать похожие значения в третий файл?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, обработка-данных

Есть 2 CSV файла: visit_log.csv и dict.csv. В первом файле колонки `user_id, source`, во втором `user_id, category`.

Необходимо найти общее значение `user_id` в обоих файлах и записать в третий файл funnel.csv с указанием категории.

Через мой код происходит перезапись, но мне кажется, что funnel.csv дублирует dict.csv:

```py
import csv

with open('funnel.csv', 'w') as response_file:
   with open('visit_log.csv', 'r') as f:
       with open('dict.csv', 'r') as s:
              for line in f.readlines():
                   for line in s.readlines(): 
                       if "user_id" == "user_id":
                           response_file.write(line)
```

Comment: какие столбцы должны быть в "funnel.csv" файле?

Comment: user_id, source, category

Comment: Это выражение всегда истинно же, поэтому и дублирует `if "user_id" == "user_id":`

Comment: если более конкретнее сказать ,есть row user_id в каждом файле и в них записаны id пользователей. Эти id нужно сравнить и если они есть в обоих файлах, записать в третий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы решал эту задачу используя модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

fn1 = r"/path/to/visit_log.csv"
fn2 = r"/path/to/dict.csv"
output_fn = r"/path/to/funnel.csv"

df1 = pd.read_csv(fn1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(fn2)
res = df1.merge(df2)
res.to_csv(output_fn, index=False)
```

вариант для <s>извращенцев</s> любителей однострочников:

```
(pd
 .read_csv(fn1)
 .merge(pd.read_csv(fn2))
 .to_csv(output_fn, index=False))
)
```

Comment: я думала использовать pandas Так все работает)

Comment: я внимательно посмотрела условие, там не нужно помешать файл visit_log.csv , в оперативную память

Comment: @Alina, ну об этом стоило упомянуть в теле вопроса ;) Сейчас я уже не буду менять ответ...